# how to complie the DPDK-1.8.0 on ubuntu 20.04.4 TLS

Tags: linux, dpdk

I download dpdk-1.8.0 on ubuntu 20.04.4 TLS. I created a file titled dpdkenv including three lines

```
export RTE_SDK=`pwd`
export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
export EXTRA_CFLAGS="-O0 -g"
```

in the dpdk root directory. Then executed `source dpdkenv`.

When I execute `make clean`. It told me

```
No .config in build directory
make[1]: *** [/home/chenglong/dpdk_study/dpdk-1.8.0/mk/rte.sdkconfig.mk:119: checkconfig] Error 1
make: *** [/home/chenglong/dpdk_study/dpdk-1.8.0/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:124: clean] Error 2
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are some build instructions under doc/build-sdk-quick.txt .  Those indicate that you must run `make config` first.

In your case, it looks like you can go with:

```
  make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc EXTRA_CFLAGS="-O0 -g" && make
```

Your bigger hurdle is that Ubuntu 20.04 runs Linux kernel v5.4 and DPDK 1.8 is from 2014 and, according to docs/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.rst, runs on Linux kernel >= v2.6.33.  The ">=" isn't quite accurate; in order to make it successfully compile, you'll probably have to update a lot of the code to comply with the newer headers.